# Assign new value to a condition selected element of an array

Tags: python, arrays, element, numpy-ndarray

I have a problem with assigning values to a selected element of an array that I do not understand why it is happening.

I'm programming in pyhton and, although the code is much more complex, the issue I am having can be reproduced with this small code:

```
Yr = np.arange(0, 10)
Xg = np.arange(0, 10)
```

Now I want to change the value of an element that I selected as follows:

```
Yr[Xg>5][2] = 10
```

... and it does nothing:

```
In [275]: Yr
Out[275]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Thank you.

I tried changing the type of assigned value, but it does not work either.

Comment: Seems like Yr[Xg>5] creates a new array and you modify that instead of the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in their answers `Yr[Xg>5]` is a new array and any change on it does not apply on the original array, but you can do it by using `np.put` like this:

```
np.put(Yr, np.where(Xg>5)[0][2], 10)
```

Or simply do this:

```
Yr[np.where(Xg>15)[0][2]] = 10
```

Comment: Ok.

Thank you. I will try this in my code.

Comment: Yes, it worked, even in the more complex case I am using in my program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome. So please accept my answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's because it creates a copy of the array
So you modify the copy and not the array itself

```
Yr[Xg>5]
```

is a new array

```py
    Yr = Yr[Xg>5]
    Yr[2] = 10
    print(Yr) # will print [ 6  7 10  9]
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it seems that the problems comes from the copy. However a need to modify the original array. May be the Mohammad's response will allow me that.